# How to play HD videos in low resolution, faster

Tags: windows, windows-xp, video, high-definition

I have a 1080p video and I want to play it in a medium configured PC running Windows XP. Since the system don't have much resources, the videos sometimes used to stall, or play in a slow motion. Is there any Software / Tool / Method to play high res videos in low res? Quality may be compromised.

Comment: If you have an GPU, you can shift video decoding to your GPU.

Comment: @HackToHell i know that, but desperately, i don't have one.. :(

Answer (score 3):

Use vlc player and follow these steps.

H.264 codecs are pretty CPU intensive and VLC can't use multi-cores to decode it yet.

So if your computer is dying when decoding 1080p samples from H264, do the following.

```
Open the preferences
Tick advanced in the lower right corner
Go to "Input/Codec"
Go to "other codecs" subcategory
Go to "FFmpeg"
Put the "skip-filter for H264" to all
Restart VLC
```

http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=42328

Download vlc from here   http://www.videolan.org/

Comment: I got it from here http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=42328

Comment: don't copy-paste verbatim from other sites. It's plagiarism.

Comment: i Know, that is why i provided the original link.

Comment: providing a 'link' doesn't mean you can do a blatant copy paste

Comment: At least rephrase the intro and reference the site *in the question*.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you don't have a GPU? Just because you don't have a video / graphics card doesn't mean you don't have a GPU. Most Mainboards have a integrated GPU. If the option isn't greyed out just try it.

But to the core problem itself:
If you have the time before watching the videos: Resize them to a lower resolution. Tools like [MeGUI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/megui/) or [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) can be utilized for that matter.

Also I recommend the site videohelp.com for issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

Software/Tool requires these in real time:

1. Reading HD video which needs same PC resources with playing HD video
2. Converting HD video to SD video which needs much more PC resources
3. Playing SD video which can be handled by your PC

However you cannot get the last step without achieving first and second steps.

As a result a video tool, which can resize videos, is the best solution for your problem. You can resize your videos with [MKVToolNix](http://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/) for mkv files and [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) for others to watch them later in the low resolution.

Answer (score 0):

VLC player has this settings on video. Go to Settings > Video (extra settings) > Preferred video resolution:

[image: on vlc, goto settings > video (extra settings) > preferred video resolution]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).